# Error Debugging - Image post being Redirected

Tags: debugging, redirect, scrape

Im getting response code 200 while trying to paste url of editorial into fb debugger.
OG Image tags are within the top 20 lines. some other posts work with no problem, others return this same response. Cannot figure why.

I copy the url from https://huntsvillebusinessjournal.com/news/2023/04/07/job-seekers-invited-to-relaunch-job-fair-on-april-11/, paste in debugger and scrape.